# Need help in formulating linear program

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

> [image]

---

Can anyone explain the following passage?

> Both semiconductors and power generation industries also want to buy as many of the remaining units as possible

How should I formulate the linear program with that?

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

As the description of the problem states, the three manufacturing sites produce a total of $270,000$ units of the product, of which exactly $60,000$ must be supplied to the medical and pharmaceutical industry, exactly $90,000$ to the aerospace industry, and at least $30,000$ to the semiconductor industry.  All the quoted passage  means is that *all* the remaining $90,000$ units produced can be sold to the semiconductor and power generation industries in any proportion that the manufacturer chooses.